# "entered the room" or "entered into the room"?

Tags: prepositions

I'd like to say that "I went into the room" using the verb "**enter**". 
What's correct in the following context?

> "I entered **the** room."

or

> "I entered **into** **the** room."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The verb *to enter*, apart from other uses that it might have, is a transitive verb that takes a direct object and does not require the use of a preposition like *into*. You always enter something. That something is usually some kind of place such as a room, house, building etc. For example:

> Although it was dark inside, I **entered the room**.

However, do not confuse the transitive verb *to enter* with the phrasal verb [**to enter into something**](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/enter-into) which itself can have a number of slightly different meanings. Though, to tell you the truth, all those meanings are just minor variations on the main one: to be an important aspect or factor of a particular situation. For instance:

> It was only after my miraculous survival of the car crash that nearly got me killed that God finally **entered into my life**.

For more information on how to use this phrasal verb, click on the blue link that I provided as part of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In "I entered the room" enter is intransitive because we can alternatively say I entered there! But when you say I entered the data into the computer, it is transitive!

Comment: Welcome to [ell.se]! Please don't leave signatures under your posts, those kind of links might be perceived as spam.

Answer (score 1):

It is fitting to use the phrase like "I entered the room" instead of "I entered into the room"  because a room is a place that shows the status of a covered place, so there is no need to use into in the middle of the aforesaid sentence.